# SharePoint 2013 email alerts format showing 2010 somehow.

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, smtp, outgoing-email

Brand new SharePoint 2013 farm.

Brand new unused web application and document library.

Enabled alerts on document library and added two files.

I received all three emails but somehow they are formatted and look like SharePoint 2010.

How would that be possible?

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have SP 2010 and the alert emails do not look any different from the 2013 ones, unless I am misunderstanding your question. It is one of those things that Microsoft never updated or improved from 2010 to 2013.

Comment: Also, by default, SharePoint 2010 WF are activated not 2013.  Since the alerts fire from the Workflow timer service, perhaps this is why also.

Comment: Both good answers. I think I'll look into changing the format.